# How can i ensure the configured JBOSS EAP 6.2 <async-handler> logging handler?

Tags: asynchronous, logging, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using the JBoss EAP 6.2 application server in my project. We are using the default JBoss Logging subsystem by configuring the loggers, handlers, and formatters as follows:

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="ACTHANDLER" autoflush="true">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-8p (%-40t) %s%E [%c] %n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="activiti.log"/>
    <rotate-size value="20m"/>
    <max-backup-index value="10"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</size-rotating-file-handler>

<logger category="org.activiti" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="ACTHANDLER"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Due to the continuous logging messages, size rotation occurs a lot and so logging latency increases. Due to this we experience performance degradation.

I studied about the `<async-handler>` option in JBoss EAP 6.2 and used it to reduce logging latency as follows:

```
<async-handler name="Async_ACTHANDLER">
    <level name="ERROR"/>
    <queue-length value="1024"/>
    <overflow-action value="discard"/>
    <subhandlers>
       <handler name="ACTHANDLER"/>
    </subhandlers>
 </async-handler>
```

Even with this `<async-handler>` I am still facing logging latency due to size rotation.

My questions are:

- How can I ensure the configured JBOSS EAP 6.2  logging handle is being used?
- Is there any other way to reduce logging latency in JBoss?

Answer (score 0):

Your logger should delegate to your Async handler, which will then delegate to your rotating file handler. So like this instead:

```
<logger category="org.activiti" use-parent-handlers="false">
<level name="DEBUG"/>
<handlers>
    <handler name="Async_ACTHANDLER"/>
</handlers>
```

You might also turn off autoflush in your rotating file handler.